# How do I use the XPath tokenizer function in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am attempting to extract information from the following HTML using Nokogiri and XPath.

```
<p>Friday, February 1<br><strong>Apple <br> Orange</strong></p>

e.xpath('./text()[following-sibling::br]')
```

Gives me the date just fine.  I want to then grab the text inside the strong node and split on br.  There may be many fruits separated by br or there may just be one with no br.  I would ideally like to accomplish this in xpath instead of code since I'm essentially defining a bunch of parsers via JSON.

Right now I'm thinking that I should use the tokenizer function and pass the text in the strong tag.  I thought that should look like this:

```
e.xpath('./strong[fn::tokenize(.,"<br>")]')
```

and have also tried

```
e.xpath('fn::tokenize(./strong,"<br>")')
```

but I am getting:

```
.../gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:159:in `evaluate': Invalid expression: ./strong/text()[fn::tokenize(.,"br")] (Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError)
```

I'm modeling my usage after the documentation for the method that the error occurs in (line 139):

```
node.xpath('.//title[regex(., "\w+")]',...
```

Comment: The `tokenize()` function is only defined in XPath 2.0. AFAIK Nokogiri only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: The fruits will be separate text nodes, e.g. `e.xpath('./strong/text()')` will work given your example.